# Is it possible to track "operations per second" of a multiprocessing program in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm writing a program that downloads thousands of images using the 'map' method in Python. It goes a bit like this,

```
def download_image(image):
    save_dir = "[PATH TO SAVE IMAGES]"
    image_url = image['url']
    image_name = image['name']

    image_data = requests.get(image_url).content
    with open(os.path.join(save_dir, f"{image_name}.jpg"), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(image_data)

from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(8)

downloads = pool.map(download_image, images)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I want to track the "downloads per second" of the program for (1) curiosity and (2) to optimize the number of processes required. It has been a while, but I remember hearing that accomplishing things like this is difficult due to the processes of Python's multiprocessing module operating independently.

One thought I've had (while writing this) is to simply time the program's runtime from 'Pool' creation to 'Pool' closing, and then divide this time by the number of images downloaded. Something about this approach seems unappealing, but if there are no better options I suppose it will have to do.

Comment: Heads up that downloading and file-writing are generally I/O bound tasks. Threading is much more suitable for this than multiprocessing.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for this info. I may be mistaken, but I've heard that Python doesn't support "true" multithreading due to the GIL?

Comment: The GIL is released by threads that "wait", such as during I/O operations. Most of downloading and file-writing is waiting for network and filesystem, it does not involve the parts of the interpreter that need the GIL for protection.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you again for the information. I am going to begin converting the program to multithreading immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you seem to be heading in an alternate direction (Threading), I figured I'd answer the original question anyway:

I'm going to to out on a limb, and assume you don't need the output of `downloads` because you don't return anything from the function `download_image` anyway. It's easy to alter this example to for example append results to a list should you need that. I'm also going to assume the order is not important also because you're not keeping the results. Given those things, I'd suggest using `imap_unordered` instead of `map` so you can effectively get a "message" every time a task is completed by one of the workers in the pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import time

def download_image(image):
    save_dir = "[PATH TO SAVE IMAGES]"
    image_url = image['url']
    image_name = image['name']

    image_data = requests.get(image_url).content
    with open(os.path.join(save_dir, f"{image_name}.jpg"), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(image_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
#   Get in the habit of never calling anything that could create a child process
#such as creating a "Pool" or simply calling "multiprocessing.Process" without
#guarding execution by "if __name__ == '__main__':". This is necessary when using
#Windows, it is needed in MacOS with python 3.8 and above, and is highly encouraged
#everywhere else
    pool = Pool(8) #  <- child processes are created here which can't be allowed
                   #     to happen when this file is `import`ed (which is what
                   #     `if __name__ == "__main__":` protects against).
    completed = 0
    t = time()
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(download_image, images):
        #`result` is unused in this case, but could easily be put to some use
        completed += 1
        if time() >= t+60: #once a minute
            rate = completed / (time() - t)
            print(f'{rate} operations per second')
            t = time()
            completed = 0
    print("done")

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment as I will undoubtedly use multiprocessing again in the future. Your answer has taught me a lot, and I appreciate you taking the time to provide this information.